# Error - First chance exception occured in webdriver.dll

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, internet-explorer-9

I have a selenium project setup in visual studio 2010 and while debugging , I am getting first chance exceptions in *webdriver.dll* with additional information:

```
unable to find xpath == .//[@id='menuForm:projectMenu_span']
```

As the error says clearly,it was unable to locate the element with *xpath*. I used *firebug* to get the *xpath.* tried using id, css *selectors*, *linktext* and none of them are working. I am using internet explorer 9. It worked for the first few times and later on started getting this exception.
Code:

```
Dim wait as WebdriverWait = New WebDriverWait(driver, Timespan.FromSeconds(10))
Dim projMenu as IWebElement = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.ElementVisible(By.XPATH(".//[@id='menuForm:projectMenu_span']")))**
```

Is there another way to handle this?

Comment: Not sure if it's just a typo, but the xpath is invalid. It should at least be like : `.//*[@id='menuForm:projectMenu_span']`

Comment: Hi, i tried using XPATH as "//div[@id='menuForm:projectMenu']"   but its not working.     below is the div tag                                                                                                 <div id="menuForm:projectMenu_span" class="rich-label-text-decor">My Projects</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
//div[contains(@id, 'menuForm')]
```

Comment: Hi @Andrew, its not working. My html code is                                                <div id="menuForm:projectMenu_span" class="rich-label-text-decor">My Projects</div>

Comment: fixed. Try once more time

Comment: Hi Andrew. I tried it and it worked. Sorry for the delayed reply.